# Заполнить оставшуюся часть массива нулями Си

Tags: c, массивы

Не могу заполнить оставшуюся часть массива нулями. Зависает окно вывода информации.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int i = 0;
    int mas[10];
    mas[0] = 555;
    mas[1] = 111111;
    mas[2] = 777;
    
    int j = 3;
    while (j < 10){
        mas[3] = 0;
    }
    
    i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
        
        printf("%d = %d\n", i, mas[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно что бы цифры "555" "111111" и "777" остались внутри массива а конец массива заполнялся нулями. Во пример что у меня получилось но терминал зависает. Наверное программа зацикливается.

Comment: Что делает первый цикл? Не что он должен делать, а что он делает?

Comment: Все у меня получилось более отвечать на этот вопрос не требуется.  я написал 'mas[j] = 0;' а потом 'j = j + 1;'

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я уже разобрался спасибо.